# Fedora and installing Ruby , using gem system , connecting MySQL to Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, fedora

I am new fedora user and I have three question . please if you can , answer to my auestion :
1 - How can I install lastest version of Ruby on fedora ?
2 - How can I use gem system in fedora ? ( when I was in windows , when I type in command prompt 'gem install algorithms' , ruby installed algorithms gem in my computer and now my question is how can I do this work in fedora ?)
3 - How can I connect MySQL to ruby in fedora ?

Please help me.
Special thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have only installed ruby on Ubuntu, however I recommend you take a look at this blog post:

http://fedoraphprails.blogspot.com/2010/07/installing-and-setting-up-rails-3-on.html

It uses RVM to install ruby which is a very common way of doing so.  It also covers installing gems.  If the RVM install doesn't work from there then try the following:

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
```

Installing mysql should be as simple as

```
yum install mysql mysql-server
```

Comment: you means that I type exactly "bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)" in terminal ?

Comment: Exactly that!  It is explained here http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/  The blog post is useful to tell you all the required libraries though.